# Dynamic pop up's on a google map by calling a cgi script that runs for ever and return's data after every cycle

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, google-maps-api-3, cgi

I am trying to implement something like google public alerts at institutional level.

I will be displaying the institution map on the home page and if there's an event , I'm trying to insert a marker for that event dynamically i.e., without the user having to refresh the map.

Unfortunately to do this, I have to use a technology called IF-MAP, which forces me to use a cgi script that keeps on repeating cycles till an interrupt is passed.

so this is how my flow is:

1. web page with google map and ajax script that calls my cgi script for data about the markers
2. a perl - cgi script that keeps polling the IF-MAP database for any updates on alerts around the campus. by the end of every polling cycle, It returns some data for the web page to bring up markers.

the problem i am facing is,

the web page doesn't bring up the markers until the cgi script finishes it's execution.

Is it possible to insert dynamic alerts on a map using my approach?
if yes, can you please suggest me how?
if no, I've heard about something called socket.io and node.js which make my connection stateful. can these technologies help me work things out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just keep it simple?

1. Poll your IF-MAP database from a cron-job or daemon
2. Write results to a JSON-formatted file
3. Make sure webserver caching/timeouts etc are setup correctly for that file
4. AJAX-GET the results file on a timer allowing the 304 unchanged status to do the hard work for you

You could try and do comlicated stuff with websockets (I think Perl's Mojolicious framework supports them out of the box) but you'll still have the issue of needing a separate process to query this IF-MAP database.